# SPA vue frontend and Laravel 7 backend Sanctum

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I created a vue and Laravel Spa using Sanctum , sent requests using axios but i get status 204 and when i tried to get user info i got **Unauthenticated**  , i dont not know what is wrong !!

This is my api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

home.vue

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  methods: {
    login() {
      axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((response) => {
         axios.post('/login',{
           email:'user@user.com',
           password:'123456789'
         })
         .then(response=>{
           console.log(response)
         })
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

dashboard.vue

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/";

export default {
 mounted(){
     axios.get("/api/user").then((response)=>{
       console.log(response);
     })
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: 204 not a error response its no content response. and what exactly the error?

Comment: i want to know why response has no content and when i try to get user data
via http://localhost:8000/api/user i get Error: Request failed with status code 401

Comment: because its json requested the login controller(laravel's default) send this response. here's the code: https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L115

Comment: oook i got it, but why i can not get user data ?

Comment: its probably because different origins means your front and backend domain not same or your front domain is not subdomain of back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!!!
By editing Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php, change *mapApiRoutes* function from middleware(['api']) to middleware(['web'])

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
```

Comment: This worked!!, Would you mind sharing the reason why this happens.

Comment: I don't know anything about PHP, so i guess you just used the web middleware instead of the api one.
So i just removed this line from the api middleware and it worked:
` \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class`
In the `Kernal.php` file

Comment: After a little bit of digging, that line is necessary, and what I found worked, is adding these environment variables in your `.env` file

`SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost`
`SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost`